# set dynamic pattern in Regexp

Tags: javascript, regex

```
var txtpattern = '/[a-z]+/';
var regex = new RegExp(txtpattern);
var result = txtstring.match(regex); //returns null
var result = txtstring.match(/[a-z]+/); //returns some value
```

My query is, Is there any way to set the dynamic pattern in match arguments?

Comment: Yes, exactly how you did it. I'd assume the expression in `txtpattern` is not correct. Maybe it includes the `/`, which are *not* part of the expression. You have to omit them. Or you did not escape the ``\`` properly. But without seeing the value of `textpattern`, these are just guesses.

Comment: Regarding your update: In the first case, your expression is `/[a-z]+/`, in the second it is `[a-z]+`. `/.../` are denoting a regex literal, much like `[...]` denotes an array literal, meaning, they are not part of your expression.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When using `new Regex()`, you need to remove the start and end `/` characters, like so:

```
var txtpattern = '[a-z]+';
var regex = new RegExp(txtpattern);
var result = txtstring.match(regex);
```