# jquery regex to test if one variable begins with another

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to test if one variable begins with another.
i.e if Var1 begins with Var2

```
regex = '/^'+var1+'/i';

if(regex.match(var2)){
return true
}
```

never returns true.

Thank you for help.

Comment: Give some examples. Also, you can't create a Regex that way. You are instead creating a string.

Comment: You can use the `RegExp` constructor, `.indexOf()`, or `.substring()` (of the several options you have)

Answer (score 1):

Your regex variable is a string, not a regular expression. You can construct literal RegExp instances with `/^foo/` but to do it dynamically you'll have to construct it like so:

```
var regex = new RegExp('^'+var1, 'i' );
```

Answer (score 1):

What you want is to create Dynamic regExp patterns. It is possible. You have to add them in the "new RegExp()" object so that this generates the correct string for the match. Check this other stakoverflow post:
[set dynamic pattern in Regexp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8730207/set-dynamic-pattern-in-regexp)

Answer (score 1):

Aside from using `.substring`, which would be a lot easier, you can't create a regex by string concatenation like that. All you are doing is making a string. What you would need is this:

```
regex = new RegEx('^'+var1, "i");

if(var2.match(regex)){
    return true
}
```

The `/foo/` notation is specifically for defining a regex in javascript and it isn't a string. It should not be enclosed in quote (single or double) and because it's not a string you can't concatenate it with a string.

```
regex = "/foo/"             // this is a string not a regex
regex = / + "foo" + /       // this doesn't work either
regex = /foo/               // this is a regex, but it's static
```

If you need to create a dynamic regex you need to use the `new RegEx` constructor.

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
var1.substring(0, var2.length) === var2
```

example:

```
var var1 = "redV", var2 = "red";
var1.substring(0, var2.length) === var2 // Returns true

var var1 = "redV", var2 = "Vred";
var1.substring(0, var2.length) === var2 // Returns false
```